# Javascript syntax error - missing )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep getting an error in Firebug regarding the `onClick` event.

I've tried various different combinations of " and ' but to no avail. This worked fine before the `onClick` event was added.

Can anybody spot what I might be doing wrong?

```
addPhoneLogo: function (n) {
    if (i.phoneLogoLink.length > 1) var t = e('<span style="position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px;"><a onclick="ga('
    send ', '
    event ', '
    Call tracking ', '
    Click to call ', '
    Menufication ');"  href="' + phoneNum + '"><img src="' + i.phoneLogo + '" id="menufication-phone-logo" /></a></span>');
    else var t = e('<span style="position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px;"><a href="' + phoneNum + '"><img src="' + i.phoneLogo + '" id="menufication-phone-logo" /></a></span>');
    n.append(t)
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use escape character to add single quotes for `onclick` parameters : Use `\'` instead of `'`

```
addPhoneLogo: function(n) {
             if (i.phoneLogoLink.length > 1) var t = e('<span style="position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px;"><a onclick="ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'Call tracking\', \'Click to call\', \'Menufication\');"  href="' + phoneNum + '"><img src="' + i.phoneLogo + '" id="menufication-phone-logo" /></a></span>');
             else var t = e('<span style="position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px;"><a href="' + phoneNum + '"><img src="' + i.phoneLogo + '" id="menufication-phone-logo" /></a></span>');
             n.append(t)
         },
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `'` by using `\`

```
addPhoneLogo: function (n) {
    if (i.phoneLogoLink.length > 1)
        var t = e('<span style="position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px;"><a onclick="ga(\'send \', \'event\',\'       Call tracking \', \'Click to call \', \'Menufication \');"  href="' + phoneNum + '"><img src="' + i.phoneLogo + '" id="menufication-phone-logo" /></a></span>');
    else
        var t = e('<span style="position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px;"><a href="' + phoneNum + '"><img src="' + i.phoneLogo + '" id="menufication-phone-logo" /></a></span>');
    n.append(t)
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
addPhoneLogo: function (n) {
    if (i.phoneLogoLink.length > 1)
        var t = e('<span style="position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px;"><a onclick="ga(\'send \', \'event\',\'       Call tracking \', \'Click to call \', \'Menufication \');"  href="' + phoneNum + '"><img src="' + i.phoneLogo + '" id="menufication-phone-logo" /></a></span>');
    else
        var t = e('<span style="position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px;"><a href="' + phoneNum + '"><img src="' + i.phoneLogo + '" id="menufication-phone-logo" /></a></span>');
    n.append(t)
},
```